# Thinking sphinx, filtering with associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, thinking-sphinx

I have serious problem with Thinking Sphinx in my Rails application. My app specifications are as follows:

- Rails 3.2.6
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Sphinx 2.0.4 (r3135)
- Thinking Sphinx 2.0.12

In my application I have a `Page` model and a `Offer` model and `pages` have many `offers`. An index defined in the `Page` model looks like this:

```
define_index do

  #other indexes defined here
  #...

  has offers.width, as: :offers_width
  has offers.height, as: :offers_height
  has offers.price, as: :offers_price

  set_property delta: true
end
```

Then I'm doing a search on the `Page` model, where `pages` are selected based on search query and conditions. However, when I'm trying to use a `:with` filter, Sphinx gave me wrong results.

When I use only one filter, for example `price` or `width`, the results are OK, however when I'm trying to combine filters, like `price and width`, I'm getting results containing offers with the given `price` OR `width`, not `price` AND `width`.

When I'm searching with ranges, most of the time `:with` parameters are ranges rather than just integer values.

**Edit 1**
Query im using:

```
Page.search Riddle.escape(query), conditions: conditions, with: has_cond, star: true, per_page: Page.per_page, page: page
```

where **has_cond** is:

```
{:offers_height=>[175..200], :offers_width=>[175..200], :offers_price=>[10..80]}
```

It still gives me pages where ***ANY*** offer has height in that range or ***ANY*** offer has width in that range or same thing with price.

Comment: Can you post the search call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a solution. The reason sphinx gave me wrong results was because he was aggregating all offers inside single page. I had to move index from page to offers, and now query works as intended. My index in offer looks like this:

```
define_index do

  indexes page(:description), as: :page_description
  indexes page(:address), as: :page_address
  indexes page(:title), as: :page_title
  indexes page(:status), as: :page_status
  indexes page.tags(:name), as: :page_tags_name
  indexes page.category(:id), as: :page_category_id
  indexes page.country(:id), as: :page_country_id
  indexes page(:verified), as: :page_verified

  has page(:id), as: :page_id
  has :width
  has :height
  has :price
end
```

I need to query sphinx first, and then do active record query.

```
@sphinx_query = Offer.search Riddle.escape(query), with: has_cond, 
    conditions: conditions, group_function: :attr, group_by: 'page_id', 
    star: true, per_page: Page.per_page, page: page
@pages = Page.find(@sphinx_query.map(&:page_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is going to be within your Search query itself. I just ran a few tests and everything is working as intended... with ranges and without.

**The search code in the controller:**

```
@titles = Title.search(params[:q], 
                              :rank_mode => :bm25,
                              :match_mode => :any,
                              :star => true,
                              :limit => 35,
                              :with_all => {
                                :runtime => [75..100],
                                :year => 1976
                              })
```

**Index code:**

```
class Title < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    define_index do
      # fields
      indexes clean_name, :sortable => true
      # attributes
      has id, year, runtime, created_at, updated_at
    end
    ...
end
```

**Search Result (JSON)**

```
{
    resultList: [
        {
            director: "Allan Arkush, Joe Dante",
            id: 34089,
            name: "Hollywood Boulevard",
            rating: "R",
            runtime: 83,
            year: 1976,
            text: "Hollywood Boulevard (1976)",
            identify: "title"
        },
        {
            director: "Patrick M. Wright",
            id: 40875,
            name: "Hollywood High",
            rating: "R",
            runtime: 81,
            year: 1976,
            text: "Hollywood High (1976)",
            identify: "title"
        }
    ],
    resultCount: 2
}
```

With the project I'm working on, it doesn't use a join table -- but that should not matter. The indexing is stil the same with the exception of a join being performed.